# How to Reverse-Geocode 330 entries fast using Google Maps v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, reverse-geocoding

1. I have about 330 entires to be reverse-geocoded(converting lat-lng
   points to street addresses).
2. I have used setInterval function to give delay for sending the
   requests
3. I am giving delay randomly in between the interval of 1-2 seconds
   for each request.
4. But as soon as the reverse-geocoding reaches 50 entires it starts
   throwing QUERY_OVER_LIMIT status and the required delay for sending
   the next request keep on increasing exponentially upto 15-20 seconds
   resulting in the output getting displayed after 20-30 minutes.

I have searched majority of stackoverflow questions as well as read the google documentation properly still none solved my problem.

I have also verified that the QUERY_OVER_LIMIT status code is due to no of requests and not due to 2500 request limit per day.

A code snippet of my project for demo(It's just a part of what I am doing and won't run)

```js
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var j = 0;
var area = [];
var time_limit = 1000;
var decoding = setInterval(function() {
  console.log("time is " + time_limit);
  time_limit = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1000);
  if (j > (employee_name.length - 1)) {
    for (var k = 0; k < employee_name.length; k++) {
      document.getElementById(k).innerHTML = area[k];
    }
    clearInterval(decoding);
  }
  if (isNaN(employee_address[j].lat) || isNaN(employee_address[j].lng)) {
    console.log("Found At " + j);
    area[j] = "Unknown Location";
    j++;
  } else {
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(employee_address[j].lat, employee_address[j].lng);
    geocoder.geocode({
      'latLng': point
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status !== google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        console.log(status);
      }
      // This is checking to see if the Geoeode Status is OK before proceeding
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var address = (results[0].formatted_address);
        area.push(address);
        console.log(j);
        j++;
      }
    });
  }
}, time_limit);
```

:

Comment: ["The per-session rate limit prevents the use of client-side services for batch requests, such as batch geocoding"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#UsageLimits) in other words, you're trying to do something Google is explicitly disallowing.

Comment: If you want to do batch requests, you should do them on the server side.  Check out the Google Maps Client Libraries: https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/client-library